# Add prefix and suffix to $@ in bash

Tags: bash

How to add suffix and prefix to `$@`?

If I do `$PREFIX/$@/$SUFFIX`, I get the prefix and the suffix only in the first parameter.

Comment: You will have to iterate over array and add prefix and suffix to each entry.

Comment: Are you looking to add a prefix an suffix to *every argument*, or add new prefix and suffix arguments on either side of the set of existing arguments? E.g. if your prefix is `P` and your suffix is `S` and `$@` is `1 2 3` are you looking for `P1S P2S P3S` or `P 1 2 3 S`?

Comment: I'm looking for `P1S P2S P3S`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would use shell  [[ parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)  for this

```
$ set -- one two three
$ echo "$@"
one two three
$ set -- "${@/#/pre}" && set -- "${@/%/post}"
$ echo "$@"
preonepost pretwopost prethreepost
```

**Notes**

- The `#` matches  the beginning
- The `%` matches  the end
- Using double quotes around `${@}` considers each element as a separate word. so replacement happens for every positional parameter

Comment: This is nice and compact.  The OP should consider making this the accepted solution.

Answer (score 10):

Let's create a parameters for test purposes:

```
$ set -- one two three
$ echo "$@"
one two three
```

Now, let's use bash to add prefixes and suffixes:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' a=($(printf "pre/%s/post\n" "$@"))
$ set -- "${a[@]}"
$ echo -- "$@"
pre/one/post pre/two/post pre/three/post
```

Limitations: (a) since this uses newline-separated strings, it won't work if your `$@` contains newlines itself.  In that case, there may be another choice for `IFS` that would suffice. (b) This is subject to globbing. If either of these is an issue, see the more general solution below.

On the other hand, if the positional parameters do not contain whitespace, then no change to `IFS` is needed.

Also, if `IFS` is changed, then one may want to save `IFS` beforehand and restore afterward.

#### More general solution

If we don't want to make any assumptions about whitespace, we can modify "$@" with a loop:

```
$ a=(); for p in "$@"; do a+=("pre/$p/post"); done
$ set -- "${a[@]}"
$ echo "$@"
pre/one/post pre/two/post pre/three/post
```

Comment: Why do we need to change IFS here? I tried without it seems to work

Comment: @Richard It is only important to change IFS if you have spaces or tabs in your parameters.  Otherwise, it is not needed.    `set` is a shell builtin that, among other things, sets the positional parameters.

Comment: Promising, but not fully robust, unless you additionally run `set -f` to turn off globbing first (and restore the previous state of the option later).

Comment: @mklement0  Where exactly do you see a "globbing" issue?

Comment: @John1024: `a=( $(echo '*') ); declare -p a`. The output from the command substitution is subject to globbing.

Comment: @mklement0 OK.  Thanks.  I updated the answer to note that that issue applies to the first approach.

Comment: `for p; do…` is equal to `for p in "$@"; do…`

Comment: @jno Yes, that can be a useful abbreviation.  I tend not to use that because I am of the explicit-is-better-implicit school-of-thought.  I do understand that other people look at it differently, though.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>Note: This is essentially a slightly more detailed version of [sjam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558776/45375).</sup>

[John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558454/45375) is helpful, but:

- requires a *subshell* (which involves a *child process*)
- can result in unwanted *globbing* applied to the array elements.

Fortunately, Bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) can be applied to *arrays* too, which avoids these issues:

```
set -- 'one' 'two' # sample input array, which will be reflected in $@

# Copy $@ to new array ${a[@]}, adding a prefix to each element.
# `/#` replaces the string that follows, up to the next `/`,
# at the *start* of each element.
# In the absence of a string, the replacement string following
# the second `/` is unconditionally placed *before* each element.
a=( "${@/#/PREFIX}" )

# Add a suffix to each element of the resulting array ${a[@]}.
# `/%` replaces the string that follows, up to the next `/`,
# at the *end* of each element.
# In the absence of a string, the replacement string following
# the second `/` is unconditionally placed *after* each element.
a=( "${a[@]/%/SUFFIX}" )

# Print the resulting array.
declare -p a
```

This yields:

```
declare -a a='([0]="PREFIXoneSUFFIX" [1]="PREFIXtwoSUFFIX")'
```

Note that *double-quoting the array references* is crucial to protect their elements from potential *word-splitting* and *globbing* (filename expansion) - both of which are instances of [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).