# bash implode array (to string)

Tags: arrays, bash, implode

i know in stackoverflow are some examples but they doesn't work as i need it,

example:

```
separator=")|("
foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')
regex="${foo[@]/#/$separator}"
regex="${regex:${#separator}}" # remove leading separator
echo "${regex}"

#output: foo bar )|(foo baz )|(bar baz
```

I would like to get:

```
#output: foo bar)|(foo baz)|(bar baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps :

**Solution 1**

```
$ foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')
$ foo=( "${foo[@]/%/)|(}" ) #appending ')|('
$ i="${#foo[@]}" #Taking array count.
$ i=$(( i - 1 )) #i points to the final array element
$ foo[$i]="${foo[$i]%)|(}" # Removing ')|(' attached to the final element
$ final="${foo[*]}" # storing array as string with space separated values 
$ final="${final//\( /(}" #stripping the whitespace after '('
$ $ echo "$final" # and that is your result.
foo bar)|(foo baz)|(bar baz
```

**Solution 2**

Okay, this would be an easier solution,  i guess

```
$ foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')
$ final="$(printf "%s)|(" "${foo[@]}")"
$ final="${final%)|(}"
$ echo "$final"
foo bar)|(foo baz)|(bar baz
```

**Note**

`printf "%s)|(" "${foo[@]}"` need an explanation I guess, So here it is

- `"${foo[@]}"` expands to each value in the array as separate word.
- `printf "%s)|("`  is applied to each of those words above where `)|(` acts as a delimiter

Comment: Also check my other answer on [\[ adding prefix and suffix to positional paramters \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38558776/1620779)

Comment: Solution 2 cannot be easily generalized to an arbitrary separator - what if the separator contains a `%` symbol?

Comment: @Leon If a character in the separator has got a special meaning inside the format string itself you may prefix it with `%`. In this case `%%` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I know. My point was that using that solution requires modifying the separator so that it is processed correctly.

Comment: @Leon : good note then, such things need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

I need more global solution for any separator so i used loop for:

```
varReturn=""

implode () { 
    local separator
    separator="$1"

    #local foo
    #foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')

    local array
    array=("${!2}")

    local newString
    newString=""
    for element in "${array[@]}"
    do
        newString="$newString$separator$element"
    done
    newString="${newString:${#separator}}"
    #echo "line $LINENO: ${newString}"
    varReturn="$newString"

    return 0
}
arr=("abc cba" 2 "tree" "z%s")
sep=")%s("
implode "$sep" arr[@]
result="$varReturn"
echo "line $LINENO: $result" #line 65: abc cba)%s(2)%s(tree)%s(z%s
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly fixed your solution:

```
separator=")|("
foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')
IFS='' eval 'regex="${foo[*]/#/$separator}"'
regex="${regex:${#separator}}" # remove leading separator
echo "${regex}"
```

Comment: you don't need `eval`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `eval` is needed to keep the effect of the changed `IFS` variable local to that command

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

joinByString() {
    local separator="$1"
    shift
    local first="$1"
    shift
    printf "%s" "$first" "${@/#/$separator}"
}

separator=")|("
foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')
output=$(joinByString "$separator" "${foo[@]}")
echo "$output"
```

source: https://dev.to/meleu/how-to-join-array-elements-in-a-bash-script-303a